# Is it better using “has been reported” to replace "is reported" in the sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is it better using “**has been reported**” to replace "is reported" in the sentence below?

> Avoid crowded places like movie theaters and shopping malls if the flu **is reported** in your town.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though both the sentences would mean same, *has been* would add *a little flair of* something happened recently.

> Avoid crowded place like movie theaters and shopping malls if the flu has been reported in your town - Health bodies detected the flu (for instance) yesterday and that's effective as of now.